# C++ prefered way to share objects between methods within the same class

Tags: c++, oop

Given a class which has two methods that need to share a variable what is the best way to pass/share that variable between them? Assuming that the variable is not needed anywhere else in the class. If that variable is an STL container, does this change anything?

I'm considering the following three options:

Instantiate variable in one method and return it by pointer, then delete it in the other method.

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        std::vector<int>* method1();
        void method2();
};

std::vector<int>* MyClass::method1()
{
    std::vector<int> *my_int_vector = new std::vector<int>;
    //manipulate the vector in some way
    return my_int_vector;
}

void MyClass::method2()
{
    std::vector<int> *myvector;
    myvector = this->method1();
    //manipulate the vector in some way
    delete myvector;
}
```

This separates the new and delete between methods which seems to be to be begging to go wrong.

Alternatively you can use a class private member property to hold the variable.

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        std::vector<int> myvector;
    public:
        void method1();
        void method2();
};

void MyClass::method1()
{
    //manipulate this->myvector
}

void MyClass::method2()
{
    this->method1();
    //manipulate this->myvector
}
```

This unnecessarily exposes the variable to the rest of the class.

Finally, you can create an object in one method and pass it by reference.

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        void method1(std::vector<int> *my_int_vector);
        void method2();
};

void MyClass::method1(std::vector<int> *my_int_vector)
{
    //manipulate my_int_vector in some way
}

void MyClass::method2()
{
    std::vector<int> myvector;
    this->method1(&myvector);
    //manipulate myvector in some way
}
```

To me this seems like the best solution as you are not calling new or delete and the variable is not available to the whole class.

Is my assessment of my alternatives correct and have I missed any other options which are better?

Answer (score 1):

The preferred way would be to make that variable a member ***if*** passing it as a parameter from one function to the other is not possible.

So yes the third option might be the best.

> If that variable is an STL container, does this change anything?

No. The containers in the C++ standard library are normal objects too.

---

About the second option:

> This separates the new and delete between methods which seems to be to be begging to go wrong.

Yes. Using raw `new` and `delete` in the first place is already begging for trouble. *Don't allocate dynamically when you don't have to.* And when you do, use smart pointers.

So in that case you could simply pass the vector by value. Or if the function is going to be called a lot then *maybe* make the vector `static` and return it by reference.

---

You mentioned about your second option that it

> unnecessarily exposes the variable to the rest of the class.

If that is *really* a problem then your class might be too big and/or trying to do too much. You should probably consider splitting the class into smaller classes with clear, minimal, well-defined responsibilities ([SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)).

Which brings us to a fourth option, which might or might not make sense in your case: Store the vector in its own class, and make the two methods members of that class. Then store that class as a member of `MyClass`.

Comment: Never make something static and return a reference for performance reasons.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Never? I'd say _measure_ if it becomes a problem. Or don't do it in the first place if you can see why it could become a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I say - make one function create the object and pass it by reference to other methods.

> To me this seems like the best solution as you are not calling new or
>   delete and the variable is not available to the whole class.

well, what difference does it make if you're creating the object with `new` ? the same problems of memory management appear with other techniques. 
and anyway, your starting point is to declare the object on the stack. try the best to keep the object stack-allocated and if it muse be on the heap - choose smart pointer to make sure no memory leak occurs.

Making some place holder for the object inside the class as static:
1) makes your class contaminated with unrelated objects
2) makes your class not thread-safe